# How to modify SELECT tag's default highlight behaviour in IE and Opera?

Tags: jquery, css, selection

Here is my HTML:

```
<select style="background-color:#e0f0f1">
  <option selected="selected">Select</option>
  <option class="" value="one">One</option>
  <option class="" value="two">Two</option>
</select>
```

[See this code in action](http://jsfiddle.net/YgAGX/)

In IE and Opera, when you select an option, it is highlighted with a blue background colour. Firefox, Chrome and Safari don't do this. Is there a way or trick to remove that blue highlight when the option is selected so that the original background colour is always shown?

If that's not possible, is there a way to add a jQuery behaviour that simulates a click elsewhere on the page right after the option is selected? So basically when you click away from the selected option, the highlight disappears.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I found a solution to this. Perhaps not a very clean solution but this trick works.

I've tested it in Firefox, Chrome, Safari, Opera and IE 9. Works on all of them but does not work on older versions of IE (6 and 7). Haven't tested in IE8. If someone can test it on Mac and let me know if this works, that'll be great.

I added an input field with width and height as 0 and shifting focus to it when an option is clicked. Using display:none and visibility:hidden in the input field does not work. So you will have hide the input field somewhere in the corner or using z-index to move it behind a container might work too (but haven't tried this). If anyone has a better solution, let me know.

HTML:

```
 `<select style="background-color:#e0f0f1">
    <option selected="selected">Select</option>
    <option class="" value="one">One</option>
    <option class="" value="two">Two</option>
  </select>
  <input type="text" id="abc" style="width:0; height:0;" />`
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('select option').on('click', function() { $('#abc').focus(); });
});
```

[See this in Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YgAGX/4/)

Comment: The input element is unnecessary.. Just blur the $('select').

Comment: I tested the solution by @user1448031 in IE8/WinXP and OSX Mountain Lion Safari 6.1.3 and it didn't work in IE8, but worked on Safari. Additionally, it works in IE9,10,11.

Answer (score 6):

In IE11 (not sure about previous versions) you can remove the blue background from a focused select element with

```
select::-ms-value {background: none;}
```

[Here's a dabblet demo](http://dabblet.com/gist/9986628)

Comment: This solution worked perfectly for me. This solution also helps us to keep the focus on the select element and we can change the options using keyboard. A problem I faced with this solution is, once we choose an option, the color of the option became white, which makes it impossible to read. We can overcome that with the same solution by making a slight change. `select::-ms-value {background: none; color: #42413D;}`

Answer (score 0):

This can't really be done as it is default browser behavior. Your best option is probably replacing the select boxes with similar functionality that can be styled, such as the [jQuery Chosen](http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/) plugin.

Comment: Unfortunately that does not seem to work well. That has no effect in Opera. In FF and IE, the dropdown does not even open.

Comment: I was afraid of that... just changed the event to 'click' and tested in Opera which seems to work. I have a Mac, so no IE.

Comment: In fact, without the function active it changes to white in Mac/Opera until it loses focus, and then you get the background color again.

Comment: I tried your changed code. I am getting different behaviours now. In FF, IE and Opera, the dropdown does not stay open when clicked. In FF and Opera, you have to keep pressing and then select an option. In IE, I am even unable to select an option- it defaults back to the first option no matter what I click.

Comment: you could try the 'change' event as well, however it won't work if you click it but don't change the option. fwiw, you can also test for different browsers with `$.browser.msie`, etc - http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.browser/

Comment: Did a bit more research and you really can't do much with that behavior on a select, your best bet is replacing it with something like jQuery Chosen - see edit.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts. I have posted a trick to make this work.