# how to replace the blue color in selectbox dropdown

Tags: javascript, css

Can someone please tell me how to change the blue color that comes up when we are navigating through options in a HTML selectbox and also when an option is selected it fills the selectbox with blue color and it happens only in IE ..Is there a way to undo that.

```
<select class="searchBox-selectbox" id="scope__1" tabindex="1" name="mode1">
    <option selected="" value="simpleall">All of the words</option>
    <option value="simpleany">Any of the words</option>
    <option value="phrase">Exact phrase</option>
</select>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to change background color of selected items in multiselect dropdown box?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13515767/how-to-change-background-color-of-selected-items-in-multiselect-dropdown-box)

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13170137/how-to-modify-select-tags-default-highlight-behaviour-in-ie-and-opera

Comment: That is different..I m talking about the blue line that comes up while navigating through the options in the dropdown

Comment: Do you mean like this? http://i.imgur.com/u1fyOnV.png?1 - @user505210 i.e blue hover in the image should change to any other color for instance red as shown in the image?

Comment: Right..That's what I want ..also when u select the option and the box colapses it makes the whole selectbox blue..Happens only in IE..any way to change that

Comment: Thanks Aaron..It's not a exact duplicate but that link solved One of the issue I had..Thanks